# Add to ListView from background worker

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, backgroundworker, show

I have a WinForm that adds some elements from a database to a listview. Since it takes quite some time to load everything I tried making a background worker. Everything works ok in the background worker except for the adding to the list code:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(event);
lvi.SubItems.Add(name);
lvi.SubItems.Add(status);
lvi.SubItems.Add(x);
lvi.SubItems.Add(y);
lvi.SubItems.Add(z);
TABEL.Items.Add(lvi);

MessageBox.Show("check");
```

The code doesn't reach the messagebox and breaks the loop. BUT if the listview is NOT visible then it does add and also the messagebox is reached.
I can make the listview visible after all adding is done, but I was wondering if there is a way to make it show at least a part of what it added at some intervals.. (eg. 25%, 50% completion)?

Comment: `it takes quite some time to load everything` - You may want to have a look at [this sort clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA).

Comment: I think, hiding the listview defeat the purpose of the bg worker. I've done exactly same stuff - fill lw using bg worker and it worked fine. Let me find the code...

Comment: You are making more than one mistake.  Start by *not* ignoring the `e.Error` property in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  It tells you what you did wrong.  You'll find *hundreds* of questions about it when you paste the exception message in the Search box.

Comment: @HansPassant I do not know how to set up the e.error message.

Comment: if (e.Error != null) MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());

Comment: @HansPassant Copied it in the Worker Completed but unfortunately it still doesn't show the errors when they come up. But I'm making some progress and probably will be posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have number of solutions. I don't think background worker thread is required for this.

For instance, you can try to:

- Use Virtual Mode : [Virtual Mode List View](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42229/Virtual-Mode-ListView)
- Use BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate(): [BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() when populating ListView](http://moiashvin-tech.blogspot.com/2007/09/use-of-beginupdate-and-endupdate-when.html)

If you decide to go with background worker, take look at: [Populating a listview from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194475/populating-a-listview-from-another-thread)

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late response. First of all it seems my problem was actually in the way I was retrieving information from the database (lots of unneeded code. I eliminated it after remembering finding about the INNER JOIN command). Still, all your answers were very useful, although I had a great pain with cross-threading now I use it easily. So I'll mark as useful and also answer because I implemented the beginUpdateMethod to speed things up even more. Cheers!